# complex eigenspace sub-bundle of holomorphic tangent bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact K"ahler manifold and let $\varphi: TX\rightarrow TX$ be a self-adjoint endomorphism of the holomorphic tangent bundle, with the property that at each point, the eigenvalues of $\varphi$ are non-zero and distinct. Using this, I am able to show that the eigenspaces actually form smooth complex sub-bundles, and hence $TX=\oplus_{i=1}^{n}L_i$ is a direct sum of complex line sub-bundles.

However, I would like to have this splitting to be as *holomorphic* sub-bundles. So my question is: Is there any conditions for which this splitting is as holomorphic sub-bundles?

In general, is there any good criteria to decide whether a smooth complex sub-bundle of a holomorphic vector bundle is holomorphic?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say, this depends on whether the map $\phi:X\to End(TX)$ is holomorphic. If so, it should be a consequence of the implicit function theorem.